# Equally split value when upsampling data

Tags: python, pandas

Using the `pandas` library in `Python`, I'm trying to upsample some data from monthly to daily values. Is there a way to evenly split a value over its resulting 'children'?

As an example, let's say I drove 100 km in both January and February:

```
In[1]: distPerMonth = pd.Series([100, 100], index=pd.PeriodIndex(['2019-01', '2019-02'], freq='M'))

In[2]: distPerMonth
Out[2]: 
2019-01    100
2019-02    100
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

Now I'd like to calculate how much this is per day, starting with

```
In[3]: distPerMonth.resample('D')....
```

which should result in

```
Out[3]:
2019-01-01    3.225806451612903
2019-01-02    3.225806451612903
...
2019-02-27    3.5714285714285716
2019-02-28    3.5714285714285716
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

(The February values higher than the January ones, due to me having driven the same distance in less days.)

What I'm looking for is a way to pass an 'aggregator' function to the resampled dataset, to which the original value, the original time period, and the 'child' time periods are available.

Many thanks!

---

PS: What is *not* working is using a custom function like so:

```
In[3]: distPerMonth.resample('D').apply(custom_function)
```

because to this function, only the child series are available (which are empty in most cases). I suppose I could use these child series to deduce which was the parent's time period, then use the parent series to get the corresponding parent value, somehow calculate how many children there are, and divide the parent value by this number, but that seems an overly convoluted way of going about things.

---

For those reading this question later: the accepted solution works in the case of gapless timeseries. If there are gaps between the rows, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834815).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
m=distPerMonth.resample('D').first()
m.groupby(m.notna().cumsum()).apply(lambda x: x/len(x.index)).ffill()
```

---

```
2019-01-01    3.225806
2019-01-02    3.225806
2019-01-03    3.225806
2019-01-04    3.225806
...
...
2019-02-25    3.571429
2019-02-26    3.571429
2019-02-27    3.571429
2019-02-28    3.571429
```

Comment: Many thanks! Seems a bit like a hack, but it works and def better than what I had come up with.

Comment: Ah, I've noticed a case where this goes wrong: if the dataframe has holes, like when I have a value for Jan and one for Mar, like so: distPerMonth = pd.Series([100, 100], index=pd.PeriodIndex(['2019-01', '2019-03'], freq='M')). In that case, the resulting dataframe should only have non-zero values for Jan and Mar. Feb should be absent. The current solution spreads January's 100 km over Jan and Feb.

Comment: I think this problem is unrelated to my original question, so I went ahead and created a separate question for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834815).