# When upscaling pandas dataframe, don't fill beyond time period of each row

Tags: python, pandas

I run into undesired behaviour when upscaling a dataframe using `Python`'s `pandas` library.

## Example

Let's start with **monthly** data:

```
carMonthly = pd.DataFrame(data={'avSpeed': [40.3, 23.4], 'dist': [100, 150]},
                       index=pd.PeriodIndex(['2019-02', '2019-05'], freq='M'))

         avSpeed  dist
2019-02     40.3   100
2019-05     23.4   150
```

Notive how I'm using a `PeriodIndex` with monthly frequency.

## Wanted outcome

Now, I want to rescale this set to **daily** values, the following way:

- the `avSpeed` values must be copied over to each of the days of that particular month;
- the `dist` values must be divided over the number of days in each month (28 for the first row, 31 for the second).

So, my preferred outcome is:

```
            avSpeed      dist
2019-02-01     40.3  3.571428
2019-02-02     40.3  3.571428
...
2019-02-27     40.3  3.571428
2019-02-28     40.3  3.571428  #until end of February
2019-05-01     23.4  4.838710
2019-05-02     23.4  4.838710
...
2019-05-30     23.4  4.838710
2019-05-31     23.4  4.838710
```

Notice how March and April are not present. If that's not possible, and the resulting resampling will always include March and April, my second-best outcome is that all rows for those months contain `NaN`-values.

## What does not work

For those interested in what I've tried:

```
carDaily = pd.DataFrame()
carDaily['avSpeed'] = carMonthly['avSpeed'].resample('D').ffill()
tempSeries = carMonthly['dist'].resample('D').first()
carDaily['dist'] = tempSeries.groupby(tempSeries.notna().cumsum())\
    .apply(lambda x: x/len(x.index)).ffill()

            avSpeed      dist
2019-02-01     40.3  1.123596
2019-02-02     40.3  1.123596
...
2019-04-29     40.3  1.123596
2019-04-30     40.3  1.123596  #until end of April
2019-05-01     23.4  4.838710
2019-05-02     23.4  4.838710
...
2019-05-30     23.4  4.838710
2019-05-31     23.4  4.838710
```

This is unwanted, as **the data for February is stretched all the way till the end of April**. Because the original dataset has a monthly frequency, and each row in the `carMonthly` dataset covers a time period of a month, I would want the copying (of `avSpeed`) or dividing (of `dist`) to be limited to those rows in the `carDaily` dataset that actually lie within the month their data is coming from, as shown under "preferred outcome".

I know why it isn't working: the resampled `Series` have `NaN` values for all rows (including March and April) except `2019-02-01` and `2019-05-01`, and at that point it's not possible to find out, what the original `start_time` and `end_time` of the months were. I just don't know, how to make it work :)

PS: The solution for the `dist` column is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55826474/equally-split-value-when-upsampling-data) question.

---

## Edit: solution

With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55835003/2302262) answer below, I'm now using this code, which allows me to build up the new dataframe column-by-column:

```
tempDf = carMonthly.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : x.resample('D').ffill())
il = tempDf.index.labels[0]
divBy = [sum(il==i) for i in il]

carDaily = pd.DataFrame()
carDaily['avSpeed'] = tempDf['avSpeed']
carDaily['dist'] = tempDf['dist'] / divBy
carDaily.reset_index(level=0,drop=True,inplace=True)
```

- What I like about this solution, is that I only need to calculate the `divBy` list once (`il = FrozenNDArray([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype='int8')`).
- It still works if I upsample from months to hours or from years to months.
- Depends only on `pandas` as external library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `resample` with in the `groupby`

```
s=carMonthly.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : x.resample('D').ffill())
s['dist']/=s.groupby(level=0)['avSpeed'].transform('count').values
s.reset_index(level=0,drop=True,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Perfect, many thanks! Any reason you're doing the counting (to know what value to divide the distance by, in the second line) on the `avSpeed` column instead of on that same `dist` column?

Comment: Another question: I'd like to build up the new dataframe column-by-column. Because more than 1 column need the `dist` treatment, I'd like to create a single `divBy` list/array which I can divide all those columns by. I could use `divBy = carMonthly['avSpeed'].groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : x.resample('D').ffill()).groupby(level=0).transform('count').values`, using a random column (here: `avSpeed`) to obtain the values. However, this is (a) cumbersome and long and (b) relies on me picking a column that only has non-NaN values. Is there a way to create this `divBy` list using only the index?

Comment: I think I figured it out and added my solution to the question.